# Add Endpoint to Serverless CLI Generated Function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am new to Serverless ([www.serverless.com](http://www.serverless.com)) and learning the CLI.

I am having trouble creating a POST, PUT, or DELETE endpoint for a function. In looking at the documentation, I used the following to create a function:

```
sls function create mycomponent/myfunction
```

This worked great, and the resulting s-function.json has a 'GET' endpoint automatically added. What I would like is to be able to add 'PUT', 'POST', or 'DELETE' endpoints on some functions.

It looks like from documentation that I could use endpoint deploy, but I attempted this and it did not work:

```
sls endpoint deploy mycomponent/myfunction@myfunction/create~POST
```

This errors out saying that no such endpoint name exists (I assume because it isn't in the s-function.json file).

Do I need to hand-code the s-function.json file to include the other endpoints, or is there a way to do this through the CLI?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just taken to updating the `s-function.json` file to set the method of an "sls" function/endpoint.

Same goes for setting specific `statusCode`, `requestTemplates`, and so on.

Here's an example of a POST function/endpoint `s-function.json` config file.

```
{
  "name": "create",
  "handler": "user/create/handler.handler",
  "timeout": 3,
  "memorySize": 128,
  "custom": {
    "excludePatterns": [],
    "envVars": []
  },
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "path": "user/create",
      "method": "POST",
      "type": "AWS",
      "authorizationType": "none",
      "apiKeyRequired": false,
      "requestParameters": {},
      "requestTemplates": "$${apiRequestTemplate}",
      "responses": {
        "400": {
          "statusCode": "400"
        },
        "default": {
          "statusCode": "201",
          "responseParameters": {},
          "responseModels": {},
          "responseTemplates": {
            "application/json": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how to add two endpoints one for POST and one for get, since we have single handler for POST only.

Comment: @johnny endpoints is a list, I think you can add your GET there

Comment: where do I find this file? can't find any reference to this in the docs

Comment: @MarcioCruz This question was made in the context of an earlier version of the serverless framework. `s-function.json` and various other `s-*` config files have been consolidated to `serverless.yml` at the root of the project.